# Update the default value of a field with a mixin or inheritance

Tags: class, object, inheritance, racket, mixins

Let's say I have some class `snack`, with a field `banana?`:

```
(define snack%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (init-field [banana? #f])))
```

Doing this, I can construct my `snack%` to have a `banana?`, or not, and the default being to not have a `banana?`:

```
(get-field banana? (new snack%))

(get-field banana? (new snack%
                        [banana? #f]))

(get-field banana? (new snack%
                        [banana? #t]))
```

Evaluates to:

```
#f
#f
#t
```

As expected.

However, now I want to construct a `snack-mixin` class, that takes a `snack%` class (or really, any class that has a `banana?` field), and changes the default value of that field to `#t`.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way to modify the default values of an inherited class (as defined in the mixin). I could not modify it, and then `set-field!` after I call `super-new`, as I do here:

```
(define (snack-mixin %)
  (class %
    (super-new)
    (set-field! banana? this #t)))
```

While this does change the default value from `#f` to `#t`

```
(get-field banana? (new (snack-mixin snack%))) ; => #t
```

It also has the negative side effect of ignoring whatever is passed into the `banana?` field, and setting it to `#t` anyway:

```
(get-field banana? (new (snack-mixin snack%)
                        [banana? #f]))
    ; => #t
```

Is there any way I can make a mixin, or make a class that inherits `snack%` that keeps the same field `banana?` (as in, does not create a new field), but changes the default value while still letting the user pick it when calling `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`super-new`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objcreation.html?q=super-new#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._super-new%29%29) form you are using there can actually take in parameters, just like `new` normally can. So just create your own `init` form, construct some `internal-banana?` object that defaults to `#t`, and pass that to `super-new`, as done here:

```
(define (snack-mixin %)
  (class %
    (init [(internal-banana? banana?) #t])
    (super-new [banana? internal-banana?])))
```

With this version of the `snack-mixin`, you get your desired behavior, the `banana?` field defaults to `#t`, and can be set to `#f` as well:

```
(get-field banana? (new (snack-mixin snack%)))

(get-field banana? (new (snack-mixin snack%)
                        [banana? #f]))

(get-field banana? (new (snack-mixin snack%)
                        [banana? #t]))
```

Evaluates to:

```
#t
#f
#t
```

As expected.

Edit: As Asumu pointed out, you don't actually need to use the identifier `internal-banana?`:

```
(define (snack-mixin %)
  (class %
    (init [banana? #t])
    (super-new [banana? banana?])))
```

This does, however, mean that the `banana?` variable and `banana?` field in your class will be bound to two separate variables.

Comment: I don't think you need the extra `internal-banana?` renaming there. This seems to work just fine: `(define (snack-mixin %)                                                                                                                                (class %                                                                                                                                               (init [banana? #t])                                                                                                                                  (super-new [banana? banana?])))`

Comment: True, although that does seem like it would have the downside that `banana?` and the `banana?` field do not like to the same thing.